# How to use PDF.JS with React?

Tags: reactjs, pdf, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I would like to parse a pdf file in a React app. The pdf will be provided through a html input.

I used `pdf-parse` - a wrapper around `pdf.js` in node - without any problem. But when it comes to React, I only receive this error:

> MissingPDFException {message: 'Missing PDF "http://localhost:3000/myfile.pdf".', name: 'MissingPDFException'}

I upload the file like this:

```js
export default function Home() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  
  const handleFile = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (d) => {
      setData(new Uint32Array(d.target.result));
    };
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>hello!</h1>
      <input
        type="file"
        accept="application/pdf"
        placeholder="insert PDF here"
        onChange={(e) => handleFile(e)}
      />
      <PDFViewer pdfFile={data} />
    </>
  );
}
```

And The file is supposed to be read here:

```js
import * as PDFJS from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf";
import * as pdfjsWorker from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry";

window.PDFJS = PDFJS;

export default function PDFViewer({ pdfFile }) {
  PDFJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker;

  const getPDFDoc = useCallback(async () => {
    const doc = await PDFJS.getDocument(pdfFile);
    doc.promise.then(
      (loadedPdf) => {
        setPdfRef(loadedPdf);
      },
      function (reason) {
        console.error(reason);
      }
    );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPDFDoc();
  }, [getPDFDoc]);
```

I doesn't seem to work at all. I have a custom config with webpack, typescript and SWC-loader. I have read all the related stackoverflow threads.

How to properly parse a PDF with PDF.js in React? If there is a better library, I'm open to any suggestions. My goal is not to display the pdf, but to get its content.

Answer (score 0):

Your component only runs `getPDFDoc` on mount since `pdfFile` is missing in the usecallback deps, so when the file changes, it probably doesn't even notice as your effect won't re-run since `getPDFDoc` is referentially stable when it shouldn't be.

Try

```
import * as PDFJS from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf";
import * as pdfjsWorker from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry";

window.PDFJS = PDFJS;

export default function PDFViewer({ pdfFile }) {
  PDFJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker;

  const getPDFDoc = useCallback(async () => {
    if (!pdfFile) return
    const doc = await PDFJS.getDocument(pdfFile);
    doc.promise.then(
      (loadedPdf) => {
        setPdfRef(loadedPdf);
      },
      function (reason) {
        console.error(reason);
      }
    );
  }, [pdfFile]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPDFDoc();
  }, [getPDFDoc]);
```

I think the reason for the weird "myfile.pdf" thing is probably because when it first runs pdfFile is not defined and this might be some internal library default. So I also added a guard to not do anything when it's not set.

Comment: Thanks for your help Adam! However, I still have the following error: "InvalidPDFException {message: 'The PDF file is empty, i.e. its size is zero bytes.', name: 'InvalidPDFException'}". Yet, the file is not empty.

Comment: This is progress I think. Have you tried logging pdf file just before you load it into the library to check what’s in there?

Comment: Also. How big is this pdf file?